# Find the number of triangular faces in a polyhedron, that has only triangles and fourgons as faces.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, polyhedra

A polyhedron has only triangles and fourgons as faces, each of its vertices has degree four, and the polygon has four fourgons. How many triangles does it have?

Comment: Is the polyhedron convex?

Comment: I guess so, but what's written is all the information I have.
I was able to figure out the number of triangles using the drawing, but I need some proof.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $q$ be the number of quadrilateral faces, and $t$ the number of triangular faces.

If you were to count the total number of corners the faces have, how many would that be (expressed in terms of $q$ and $t$)? You are also given that the vertices have degree 4, so now express the total number of corners that the faces have in terms of $v$ (the number of vertices).

The above counts the number of corners in two different ways, and this gives you an equation that expresses $v$ in terms of $q$ and $t$.

You can do a similar thing by counting the sides of the faces in two different ways to create an equation that expresses $e$ (the number of edges) in terms of $q$ and $t$.

It is trivial to express $f$ (the total number of faces) in terms of $q$ and $t$.

So now every variable in Euler's identity, $v-e+f=2$, can be substituted by something involving only $q$ and $t$.

It turns out that you don't even need to know the value of $q$ - it drops out of the equation - so you then have an equation for $t$ alone, and can deduce its value.

Comment: Note that this solution only works if the polyhedron is convex; otherwise, $v-e+f$ is the [Euler characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic), which need not be $2$.

Comment: @vadim123 It has to be topologically equivalent to a sphere, i.e. not have any holes or handles, nor can it self-intersect. It IS allowed to be non-convex, i.e. it is allowed to have 'dents'.

Answer (score 0):

Use Euler's identity for planar graphs to set up system of equations.

Comment: I know that Euler's identity is a go-to in this case, but I don't understand how to manipulate all the info given in this problem, I feel like it's too little information.